# MissingManifestResourceException on configuring NHibernate with SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, sqlite

I've been trying to configure NHibernate with SQLite database, and i'm seemed to be stuck with an exception i do not know how to handle.

Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Data Source=mynewdatabase.dbf;Version=3
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true=1;false=0</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And here's my person.hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="SQLiteObjects"
               namespace="SQLiteObjects.Domain">
  <class name="Person">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="guid" />
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName" />
    <property name="LastName" />
    <property name="Age" />
    <property name="Height" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When running the following code, I get a MissingManifestResourceException (on the last line)

```
    var cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.Configure();
    cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Person).Assembly);
    new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false);
    PersonRepository pr = new PersonRepository();
    cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

I'm using .NET 4.0 on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Would really appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: try getting into Fluent Nhibernate. It's much easier to configure, and there's no need for those messy xml configuration files... :)

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of [SQLite for .NET](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) is distributed as 2 dlls.

- System.Data.SQLite.dll
- SQLite.Interop.dll

Both dlls need to be present in the same folder as your EXE. Interop dll is platform specific so you have to manually (or Post-build) copy x86 or x64 version.

Another thing to keep in mind is that **SQLite.Interop.dll** itslef depends on **MSVCR100.DLL** (part of Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package). You can get it here:

- [64 bit version](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)
- [32 bit version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328)

Also make sure that you download it from the new web site, the project is now supported by SQLite team:

> The folks at SQLite.org have taken over ownership of the
>   System.Data.SQLite project.  New releases can be found at the new
>   site, System.Data.SQLite.org